# Повышение привилегий во время выполнения

Tags: python, gtk, ubuntu

Привет, пишу программу на питон под убунту, суть такова:

Когда мы запускаем программу, мы можем смотреть все, что там есть.
Когда мы хотим что-то поменять, мы жмем кнопку "Разблокировать", вылезает системный диалог с запросом пароля рута, после чего программа выполняет некие административные действия в системе.
Как вот такую разблокировку налету сделать? Вариант - запросить пароль самодельным диалогом и потом через шелл тупо через sudo нужное сделать, но хочу больше нативности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если GUI, то есть gksudo. Если ваша программа консольная - sudo. В любом случае пароль не должен проходить через вашу программу.

Comment: спасибо, плюсануть кармы не хватает

Comment: спасибо, товарищи добавили :)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант воспользоватся [ssh-askpass](http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/sudo-with-askpass/):

```
$ SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/x11-ssh-askpass sudo -A /path/to/script
```

UPD. Кстати, диалоговое окно при этом предельно просто реализуется. Можно как-то так сделать. `askpass.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLineEdit, QInputDialog

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    password, result = QInputDialog().getText(None, QString(u'Пароль'),
        QString(u'Введите свой пароль: '), QLineEdit.Password)

    if result:
        print(password)

    app.exit()
```

И затем вызывать:

```
$ SUDO_ASKPASS=/path/to/askpass.py sudo -A /path/to/script
```